# How to structure a Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

Hello I'm new to Ruby on Rails. 
But for fun I would like to make a WebApp to sell tickets.
So I have made the login system and the event model. How do I integrate the tickets? Do I make another model called Tickets and connect it through has_many to the events model?
What would be the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes.

`Ticket` and `Event` will have one-to-many relationship.

also you may want to add a relation between `User` and `Ticket` so you can retrieve users tickets later.